# pandas shift converts my column from integer to float

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

`shift` converts my column from integer to float. It turns out that `np.nan` is float only. Is there a way to keep the shifted column as integers?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":range(5)})
df['b'] = df['a'].shift(1)

df['a']
# 0    0
# 1    1
# 2    2
# 3    3
# 4    4
# Name: a, dtype: int64

df['b']

# 0   NaN
# 1     0
# 2     1
# 3     2
# 4     3
# Name: b, dtype: float64
```

Comment: you can use this hack: `df['b'] = df['a'].shift(1).fillna(-1).astype(df.a.dtype)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another solution starting from pandas version `0.24.0`: simply provide a value for the parameter `fill_value`:

```
df['b'] = df['a'].shift(1, fill_value=0)
```

Comment: [Changed in version 0.24.0.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

Answer (score 17):

A solution for pandas under 0.24:

The problem is you get a `NaN` value that is `float`, so `int` is converted to `float` - see [na type promotions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#na-type-promotions).

One possible solution is convert `NaN` values to some value like `0` and then it is possible convert to `int`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":range(5)})
df['b'] = df['a'].shift(1).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
   a  b
0  0  0
1  1  0
2  2  1
3  3  2
4  4  3
```

A solution for pandas 0.24+ - check [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

> **fill_value** object, optional
> The scalar value to use for newly introduced missing values. the default depends on the dtype of self. For numeric data, np.nan is used. For datetime, timedelta, or period data, etc. NaT is used. For extension dtypes, self.dtype.na_value is used.
>
> Changed in version 0.24.0.

```
df['b'] = df['a'].shift(fill_value=0)
```

Comment: Another issue is if the shift introduces a NaN thereby converting all integers to floats, there's some rounding that happens (e.g. on epoch timestamps) so even recasting it back to integer doesn't replicate what it was originally. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: @guy: It should be possible to use `convert_dtypes` function for this case as you can see in @totalhack answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60802882/7964098)). It should convert your data to so called `ExtensionDtype` which will stay integer but with support for `pd.NA`, so you can use `shift` method that will not convert your integers to floats as you have converted it to integer type with `NA` support.

Answer (score 4):

You can construct a NumPy array by prepending a `0` to all but the last element of column `a`:

```
df.assign(b=np.append(0, df.a.values[:-1]))

   a  b
0  0  0
1  1  0
2  2  1
3  3  2
4  4  3
```

Answer (score 4):

As of pandas 1.0.0 I believe you have another option, which is to first use [convert_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.convert_dtypes.html). This converts the dataframe columns to dtypes that support pd.NA, avoiding the issues with NaN.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":range(5)})
df = df.convert_dtypes()
df['b'] = df['a'].shift(1)

print(df['a'])
# 0    0
# 1    1
# 2    2
# 3    3
# 4    4
# Name: a, dtype: Int64

print(df['b'])
# 0    <NA>
# 1       0
# 2       1
# 3       2
# 4       3
# Name: b, dtype: Int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the [replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) function and typecast:

```
df['b'] = df['a'].shift(1).replace(np.NaN,0).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like other answers which may change original dtypes. What if you have float or str in the data?

Since we don't need the first nan row, why not skip it?

I would keep all dtypes and cast back:

```
dt = df.dtypes
df = df.shift(1).iloc[1:].astype(dt)
```