# Is it possible to use pandas shift function and keep the dtypes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When using the method shift from Pandas it reassigns dtypes different from the original dataframe, is it possible to shift without that happening? (but still using pandas shift)

Using `fill_value` argument is almost enough, but if there is any dtype that is not numeric it still changes the dtype.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
  {'a': 1, 'b': 5.2, 'c': True},
  {'a': 5, 'b': 8.5, 'c': False},
  {'a': 2, 'b': 2.6, 'c': True}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df.dtypes)
print(df.shift(1).dtypes)
print(df.shift(1, fill_value=0).dtypes)
```

Output:

```
a      int64
b    float64
c       bool
dtype: object

a    float64
b    float64
c     object
dtype: object

a      int64
b    float64
c     object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas shift converts my column from integer to float.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870093/pandas-shift-converts-my-column-from-integer-to-float)

Comment: It does not, I've updated the question to explain it better.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`convert_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html) like:

```
print (df.shift(1).convert_dtypes().dtypes)
a      Int64
b    float64
c    boolean
dtype: object
```

It is not exactly `bool` type but [`boolean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/boolean.html) but it is better than object I guess